# Get random sample, calculate divisions, and repeat process 1000 times

Tags: r, dataset

I have a categorical data column (Urban.f) in a dataset (edu2018) and would like to calculate a division and repeat the process 1000 times.

This is the code I have to get a random sample of size 300. It shows me how many cases of "Urban" and "Rural" there is, along with the rest of columns in the dataset. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZYOB.png)

```
x1 <- sample_n(edu2018, 300, fac = "urban.f")
summary(x1)
```

I want to calculate the number that appears in "Urban" by the sum of "Urban" + "Rural".

Then, I want to repeat this step 1000 times. I have tried this code that tries to englobe everything I want, but cannot make it work.

```
edu2018_df <- edu2018$urban.f
n <- 1000
sample_rural <- replicate(n, {edu2018_df <- sample(edu2018, 300, replace = TRUE)
               count(sample_rural = "Urban")/count(sample_rural == "Urban","Rural) * n})

hist(sample_rural)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
sample_rural <- replicate(1000, sum(sample(edu2018_df, 300, F) == 'Rural')/300)

hist(sample_rural)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your actual data, so I recreated your vector `edu2018_df`, which is simply a vector of "Rural" and "Urban"

```r
set.seed(1)
edu2018_df <- sample(c("Rural", "Urban"), 1000, TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Allan! It worked beautifully. In the code "sum(sample(edu2018_df, 300, F) == 'Rural')/300)", could you explain why there is a 300 in the end? The result is correct, I just don't understand that part.

Comment: You are drawing 300 samples from the vector each time. The proportion of them that are rural is the number that are rural divided by the sample size. For example, if you sample 300 from your vector and find that 150 are rural and 150 are urban then the proportion that are rural is 150/300 = 50%

Comment: Oh totally get it right now, thank you very much for all your help!